# Unable to convert url image response to buffer using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, buffer, response

I am working on downloading image from url using nodejs. But I am unable to convert response to buffer. Image I receive from response is in gibberish form..
Following is my code:

```
app.get('/test', async (req, res) => {
  const data = await fetch("https://api.image/test.jpg");
  res.send(Buffer.from(data));
});
```

Response of fetch API is:
[image]

Error after downloading image is:

[image: Image is]

I also tried following buffer encoding but I still getting above error after downloading image:

```
 Buffer.from(data,'base64');
 Buffer.from(data,'ascii');
 Buffer.from(data,'base64url');
 Buffer.from(data,'binary');
 Buffer.from(data,'hex');
 Buffer.from(data,'latin1');
 Buffer.from(data,'ucs-2');
 Buffer.from(data,'ucs2');
 Buffer.from(data,'utf-8');
 Buffer.from(data,'utf16le');
 Buffer.from(data,'utf8');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should be like:

```js
app.get('/test', async (req, res) => {
  const data = await fetch("https://api.image/test.jpg");
  res.send(Buffer.from(await data.arrayBuffer()));
});
```

Comment: Tried, Not Working

Comment: It works for me, what's the error message, and which framework do you use, express?

Comment: I am getting error: "Error :  TypeError: data.arrayBuffer is not a function"

Comment: It is working... Thank you very much

Comment: I am curious about why you were getting the "data.arrayBuffer is not a function" error before (Also it may help others)

Comment: @ZhengBowen what if I am using axios, as far as i know axios only provides json response.